# How to add a reference to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, .net-assembly

How can I reference a .NET assembly deployed in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly from Visual Studio IDE?
If i do right click on References/Add Reference, it only shows the c:\windows\assembly content.
How do I add a reference to new GAC path (c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly)?

Comment: The Visual Studio "Add Reference" dialog doesn't use the GAC at all. It uses references assemblies located with `C:\Program Files (x86)`. The GAC (whichever one) is only used at runtime

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The assemblies listed under "Framework" are the reference assemblies, but the assemblies listed under "Extensions" aren't, are they?

Comment: @hvd - no, but they're still not from the GAC.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the location via CMD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
2. Type Gacutil -i {Path of the dll}

OR

Open visual studio commond promt and type Gacutil -i {Path of the dll}

Answer (score -1):

It's working by adding a reference to:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\\

I don't know if it is the better way to do it but it seems to do the job.

For registering the DLL in another environment, I used the following sentence:

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i  /f

Hope it helps.